# Changing button text and destination on jQuery event

Tags: jquery, button, text, submit

Here's my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#url").bind("textchange",showPage);
    $("input#url").focus();


    $("form#surlform").submit(function(){
        var url = $("input#url").val(); 
        $.get("api/create.php?url=" + url, function(data) {
                $("input#url").val(data);
                $("input#url").select();
            });

        return false;
    });
    });

$(document).click(function(){
    showPage();
});
$(document).mousemove(function(){
    showPage();
});
```

At the moment, when the form is submitted, jQuery stops it from reloading the page, and simply pulls the required output from the API. 
If possible, I'd like to make it also change the button, so that the button text is different, and it links to a page instead of submitting the form with jQuery. (If it helps, the button it changes to can be a div - only the original button needs to be button for form).

That's not all...
I'd then like it to change BACK to the button that submits the form via jQuery with the original text when the text in the text field is altered.

This is quite a big ask, but if anyone's got a way to go about this, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What button? We might need to see some HTML. The easiest way to do it would be to have 2 buttons - one for the submit, one for the link. Then you just toggle them depending on the state.

Comment: @ChristianVarga the jQuery above just acts on form submit, and doesn't interact with the button currently at all. Form HTML is just: <form id="surlform"> 
<div id="url-box">
  <div id="input"><input type="text" id="url" autocomplete="off" /></div>
  <button id="button">Shorten</button>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
</form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jqfjC/)?:

HTML:

```
<form id="someForm">
    <input id="someInput" type="text" />
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" />
    <input id="linkButton" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>​
```

CSS:

```
#linkButton { display: none; }​
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#someForm').submit(function () {
    $('#submitButton').hide();
    $('#linkButton').show();
    return false;
});

$('#linkButton').click(function () {
    alert('use something like window.location here to act like a link');
});

$('#someInput').change(function () {
    $('#linkButton').hide();
    $('#submitButton').show();
});
```

It's overly simple at the moment and could likely use some improvement, but the idea is straightforward enough...

1. When the page initially loads, the "link" button is hidden.
2. Any time the "submit" button is clicked, the "submit" button is hidden and the "link" button is shown.  (Naturally *after* whatever AJAX you're doing, not included here for brevity.)
3. Any time the "link" button is clicked, do something.  In your case it's to act as a link, right?  `window.location = 'some new location';` essentially.
4. Any time the text changes, the "link" button is hidden and the "submit" button is shown.  In the event that they were already hidden and shown, no harm done.  (There's probably a more elegant and less show-and-hide-every-time way to do this, but it gets the job done.)

Comment: thanks for this, all is working! One last thing though - in my code above you can see that it changes the value of the text box to the data output from the API. Is there any way I can set this as the target for window.location?

Comment: @HenryCole: The easiest way is probably to just have a variable outside of all the function calls to store the URL.  Set the value of it in the AJAX call and use its value in the link button click.  Also do some error checking in that click handler to make sure the value is good before using it (that it's a URL, etc.).